# online nikkah is?

Tags: nikah

I wanted to ask if the girl and the boy get nikkah online without telling at home.so this nikkah is done.nikkah is such that the one who is a boy had a man on his side.He has given sermon before.Then said he asked the girl to ask him three times that she accepts him,Thrn in the same way he asked the boy that he accepts her,three times both said yes three times.then at the end,one read both short surh and when a prayer was asked,this nikkah took place,And the girl also that we will get nikkah again in front of our parents,this time we will ask for dowry.And...So they did not tell the house.That their parents didn't want yet.And the girl and the boy loved each other very much.They wanted to be with each other.And both were from different countries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get married without the witnesses or any other marriage formalities?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51817/can-i-get-married-without-the-witnesses-or-any-other-marriage-formalities)

Comment: @UmH this makes me curious about situations where a guardian is not well at hand. Having died recently, or being at a long distance (journey), how can I phrase this into a question?

Comment: @GyroGearloose I guess something like 'How can a woman get married if her father has died?' or ' ... is in a far away location' etc. But things like this might already be covered under the [wali](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wali) tag. In short guardianship travels down to other blood relations when some have died, and a living guardian could make another person as his agent.